# How do I find company exposures to specific loan types?

Tags: stocks, loans

I think student loan liabilities are likely to become a big problem pretty soon. How do I find the companies that would be most exposed to this? not sure where to start.

Comment: exposed to student loans directly (presumably financial institutions and hedge funds) - or exposed to demand for studies?

Comment: Another exposure angle may be employees - employees saddled with debt may affect the company performance through higher salary demands

Comment: directly, focused on public companies only